# Discrepancy between JSON from API received by IOS app vs. viewed in Postman or browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession

I am using `NSURLSession` to receive JSON from an API written in PHP that pulls from a MYSQL database.

For one query from a certain MYSQL table, the phone cannot seem to read the JSON produced by the API even though it looks fine in Postman and the browser. In fact, I configured another table and query to produce the exact same JSON and the phone can read it without any problem.  The only thing I can think is that there are invisible characters in the JSON from the problem table and query that are throwing things off. I compared the headers for the queries from the two tables in Postman and they are the same.

Is NSURLSession known to have any problems with hidden characters or the like?

This is what the JSON looks like pretty printed in Postman:

```
{
    "comment": [
        {
            "response": "you haven't been paying attention"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what the browser shows:

```
"comment":[{"response":"you haven't been paying attention"}]}
```

This is what the Xcode console shows:

```
comment = "0(NSNull)"
```

Here is the Objective-C code:

```
NSURL *dataUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *data =[session dataTaskWithURL:dataUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSData *jsonFeed = data;
        NSLog(@"jsonFeed is%@",jsonFeed);
        if (data != nil) {
             NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonFeed
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json in async is:%@",json);
        }
    }];
    [data resume];
```

Comment: is there any header required? check headers in postman and pass the same header.

Comment: POSTMAN has a feature that can generate Objective-C. It's not beautiful Objective-C code, but it could help you understand what's different.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are passing wrong `Content-Type`. Please pass the correct `Content-Type` in the request.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Create Request using `NSMutableURLRequest`, Here is a good example to make a request please check this one. [Link](https://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)